# How to change border of div containing radio button when checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a piece of code I use to check a radio button contained in a div where anywhere in the div is clicked to choose a product. I need to add a border because the div is a photo and I have hidden the button so it is not in the photo and I need my customer to know it is checked. The code is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$("div.div-check").on("click",function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('input:radio')) return;
    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='radio']");

    if( !checkbox.prop("checked") ){
        checkbox.prop("checked",true);
        $('input:radio').filter(':checked').parent().addClass('checked');
    } else {
        checkbox.prop("checked",false);
    }
});
//]]>  

</script>
```

Also, I was wondering if this code is vulnerable since the script is changing the checked. Thanks in advance!

New:
I think my original question and code was made confusing by me because of the following piece of my code.

```
$('input:radio').filter(':checked').parent().addClass('checked');
```

That was just my guess at how to get the border and I didn't mean for it to be in the code I posted. I was guessing the way to accomplish the border was to add a class called "checked" which I could style in my css. The .css answer below I had not heard of. I think the .css answer posed below made the need for the line below useless as the border shows just the same as a script without that line.

```
$('input:radio').filter(':checked').parent().addClass('checked');
```

However, I edited the code to the code below suggested by tchoow002, but I still have a problem. When a user clicks another choice after choosing a choice beforehand, the border stays red even though the new choice is selected. The value returned is correct but the red border on the first choice stays on.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$("div.div-check").on("click",function(event) {
var target = $(event.target);
if (target.is('input:radio')) return;

var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='radio']");

if( !checkbox.prop("checked") ){
checkbox.prop("checked",true);
$('input:radio').filter(':checked').parent().addClass('checked');
checkbox.parent().css("border","1px solid red");
} else {
checkbox.prop("checked",false);
checkbox.parent().css("border","none");
}
});
//]]>  
</script>
```

I tried adding the code to the else statement below but it did not work. Also on the original code I posted

```
$('input:radio').filter(':checked').parent().removeClass('checked');
```

Comment: Why don't you just include the border in the CSS for the `checked` class?

Comment: And in the code that unchecks the box, use `removeClass('checked')`.

Comment: I guess that is what I am asking, thanks. How would I do that in css? I am not sure how my guess would be:

Comment: `.checked { border: whatever; }`

Comment: I guess that is what I am asking, thanks. How do I style a particular that in css? I am not sure how my guess would be: div.div-check.input[type="radio"] {border:1px solid red} but it doesn't work.

Comment: you do exactly what I wrote. Why are you trying to make it more complicated?

Comment: `div.checked { border: 1px solid red; }`

Comment: will that not change the border of all things checked on the page not just ones in one particular div?

Comment: I assumed you're only using `.checked` for the things you want to add a border to. If not, use another class for this.

Comment: I tried that earlier but it doesn't work

Comment: Show what you tried. Maybe make a fiddle showing your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

> Use .css() to get the value of a style property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more CSS properties for every matched element.

So if you wanted to set the css property for border for your checkbox's parent div you could do:

To add the border: `checkbox.parent().css("border","1px solid red")`

To remove the border: `checkbox.parent().css("border","none")`

Like this:

```
if( !checkbox.prop("checked") ){
    checkbox.prop("checked",true);
    $('input:radio').filter(':checked').parent().addClass('checked');
    checkbox.parent().css("border","1px solid red");
    $('input:radio').not(':checked').parent().removeClass('checked').css("border", "none"); //Remove border and checked class from all other radios that are not checked
} else {
    checkbox.prop("checked",false);
    checkbox.parent().removeClass('checked'); //remove checked class when clicked twice
    checkbox.parent().css("border","none");
}
```

Or

Use `.addClass` to add an additional css class that contains your border.

And `.removeClass` to remove it

Comment: It would be beneficial to put the answer in context of the original code given.

Comment: Thank you! I figured I would have to add a class but was unsure how to alter it! .css() is awesome! I am just learning php,html, and css and wasn't sure how to correctly google what I was trying to do.

Comment: tchow002 I still have a problem. When a user clicks a choice after first clicking anther choice the red border stays on the first choice.  The result of the radio button is correctly shifted but the event of the second choice doensn't clear the border of the first choice.

Comment: Updated answer. When you click and set a border you now will also check all other radios that are not checked and remove their border/checked class. I also added a bit to remove the checked class when you click on it twice in the `else` clause.

Comment: tchow002 thank you so much! The code also doesn't interfere with other checkbox fields in my form which I was concerned about when presenting them in the form in this manner! May tons of good karma come your way.